# Programmatic UIButton Constraints Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, ios-autolayout

I'm building a view programmatically where a blue button is supposed to be laid out in the center of the screen under a user image, but it's getting constrained to the top left corner every time. I have self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints set to false in the init method of this view. Here is my code where I restrain this button:

```
addSubview(continueMessagingButton)

continueMessagingButton.anchor(top: currentUserImage.bottomAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 32, left: 48, bottom: 0, right: 48), size: .init(width: 0, height: 60))
continueMessagingButton.layer.cornerRadius = 30
```

Here is an image of what's happening:

[image: UIButton Constraining to Top]

Please help thank you!

full code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseAnalytics

class MatchView: UIView {

var userId: String! {
    didSet {
        API.User.observeCurrentUser { (user) in
            self.currentUserImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: 
user.profileImages!.first!))
            self.currentUserImage.alpha = 1
        }
        API.User.observeUsers(withId: userId) { (user) in
            self.otherUserImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: 
user.profileImages!.first!))
            self.otherUserImage.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}

let partyPopperImage: UIImageView = {
   let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: 
"party-popper-emoji"))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    return imageView
}()

var username: String! {
    didSet {
        descriptionLabel.text = "Congratulations!\n\(username!) is 
interested in you!"
    }
}

let descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
   let label = UILabel()
    label.text = ""
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.08732911403, green: 
0.7221731267, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 19)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

let currentUserImage: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    imageView.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.08732911403, 
green: 0.7221731267, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    imageView.alpha = 0
    return imageView
}()

let otherUserImage: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    imageView.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.08732911403, 
green: 0.7221731267, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    imageView.alpha = 0
    return imageView
}()

let continueMessagingButton: UIButton = {
   let button = GlympsGradientButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("CONTINUE MESSAGING", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, 
alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.08732911403, green: 0.7221731267, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    return button
}()

let messageLaterButton: UIButton = {
    let button = GlympsGradientBorderButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Message Later", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.08732911403, green: 
0.7221731267, blue: 1, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.backgroundColor = .clear
    return button
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    continueMessagingButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = 
true

    setupBlurView()
    setupLayout()
    //setupAnimations()

    let tap = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
#selector(handleDismiss))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: 
.light))

func setupAnimations() {

    let angle = 30 * CGFloat.pi / 180

    currentUserImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: - 
angle).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 200, y: 0))
    otherUserImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 
angle).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -200, y: 0))
    continueMessagingButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 
-500, y: 0)
    messageLaterButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 500, 
y: 0)

    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.3, delay: 0, options: 
.calculationModeCubic, animations: {

        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 
0.45, animations: {
            self.currentUserImage.transform = 
CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -angle)
            self.otherUserImage.transform = 
CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
        })

        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.8, 
relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.currentUserImage.transform = .identity
            self.otherUserImage.transform = .identity
        })

    }) { (_) in

    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, delay: 0.6 * 1.3, 
usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: 
.curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.continueMessagingButton.transform = .identity
        self.messageLaterButton.transform = .identity
    })

}

func setupLayout() {

    addSubview(partyPopperImage)
    addSubview(descriptionLabel)
    addSubview(currentUserImage)
    addSubview(otherUserImage)
    addSubview(continueMessagingButton)
    //addSubview(messageLaterButton)

    partyPopperImage.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: 
descriptionLabel.topAnchor, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 
0, bottom: 16, right: 0), size: .init(width: 150, height: 150))
    partyPopperImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    descriptionLabel.anchor(top: nil, leading: self.leadingAnchor, 
bottom: currentUserImage.topAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor, padding: 
.init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 32, right: 0), size: .init(width: 0, 
height: 80))

    currentUserImage.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: nil, 
trailing: centerXAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, 
right: 16), size: .init(width: 140, height: 140))
    currentUserImage.layer.cornerRadius = 70
    currentUserImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    otherUserImage.anchor(top: nil, leading: centerXAnchor, bottom: 
nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 
0), size: .init(width: 140, height: 140))
    otherUserImage.layer.cornerRadius = 70
    otherUserImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    continueMessagingButton.anchor(top: currentUserImage.bottomAnchor, 
leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: trailingAnchor, padding: 
.init(top: 32, left: 48, bottom: 0, right: 48), size: .init(width: 0, 
height: 60))
    continueMessagingButton.layer.cornerRadius = 30

//        messageLaterButton.anchor(top: 
continueMessagingButton.bottomAnchor, leading: 
continueMessagingButton.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: 
continueMessagingButton.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 16, left: 
0, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: 0, height: 60))
//        messageLaterButton.layer.cornerRadius = 30

    self.layoutIfNeeded()

}

func setupBlurView() {

    addSubview(visualEffectView)
    visualEffectView.fillSuperview()
    visualEffectView.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 
1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.visualEffectView.alpha = 1
    }) { (_) in

    }

}

@objc func handleDismiss() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 
1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0
    }) { (_) in
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}




required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: Have you also set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for the continueMessagingButton itself?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth No I did not. I changed it from self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false to continueMessagingButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false within init(). Still not working :(

Comment: If you show the full code then perhaps the issue will be clear.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I just added the full code. Please let me know if you see anything out of the ordinary. Thanks!

Comment: Too much code. Figure out the minimum needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I figured out the issue. Everything is laid out fine when I create both of my buttons as type UIButton. But if I try to make them a custom button class I created (special gradient-colored button), I get my problem. Any ideas why?

Comment: @matt any ideas as well?^^^

Comment: Evidently your custom button class is the issue.

Comment: Yep strange but there must be something in the GlympsGradientButton causing the issue.

Comment: What if you change your GlympsGradientButton(type: .system) to default UIButton, if it's works properly then the problem is in your custom button. Otherwise, could you upload your part of code that contain this problem to github or somewhere else?

Answer (score -1):

I've figured out the issue. For my gradient colors I had:

```
let leftColor = UIColor.blue
let rightColor = UIColor.green

gradientLayer.colors = [leftColor, rightColor]
```

Once I added .cgColor to the ends of these, it worked:

```
gradientLayer.colors = [leftColor.cgColor, rightColor.cgColor]
```

Super minor, but this fixed the gradient!

I also needed to change the frame from

```
self.frame
```

to

```
gradientLayer.frame
```

Also minor, but this fixed the button location.

Comment: This answer does not correspond to the question that was asked.